# Using View in worker thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask, picasso

Written a utility class which is downloading image. Using this class I need to show this downloaded image into a image view.

Since the image downloading code is running in worker thread I cannot use the `imageView` inside the worker thread for setting the image.

I want to know how [Picasso library](http://square.github.io/picasso/) is doing similar task in which user is passing `imageView handle` and `Picasso` is setting the image, so that I can use the same logic in my code instead of using `LocalBroadcastReceiver`.

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Comment: Pass the image in a method run on the main thread, where you set it on the `ImageView`.

Comment: You linked to picass page which links to Github where all the sources are for you to check...

Comment: Piccasa is giving a lot of scenarios for our own implementation in example. Target interface and so on. The point it is callback oriented, and that's the most suitable approach for many cases. So just pass your bitmap through a callback on UI tread.

Answer (score 0):

Got answer my question, may be helpful to other

View handle is passed and the worker thread will need to post message to UI thread as below.

```
imageView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        }
                    });
```